# simultaneous storyboards in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have looked everywhere I could think of, but I can't find the answer to this...

I want to make a sort of template Storyboard for windows phone 7 (xaml and c#), and then to use that storyboard to animate multiple objects the same way. (i.e. rotating all objects 90 degrees at the same time)  Any ideas?

It has to be dynamically done. By that I mean that I want to assign different objects to several different storyboards during the program, so it can't be something static.

The main problem that I have faced up to this point is that a storyboard must be stopped before it can be used again, therefore they can't be simultaneously running.  I was thinking however that if I could make temporary copies of the Storyboard, that I could run them all at the same time? Please give me any ideas that you have.  Thanks in advance!

I initialize my objects (rectangles) in a grid as such:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <Rectangle Name="rec1" Height="80" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,140,0">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="rec1Transform" Angle="0" CenterX="5" CenterY="-10" />
      </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
   </Rectangle>
   <Rectangle Name="rec2" Height="10" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,55,0">
   .
   .
   .
   </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

At this moment, I have 4 general storyboards that I want to use many times over, and I am using a series of buttons to imitate all of the animations.  For example:

**My Storyboards**

```
private void rotate1(object parameter, object secondParameter, String Target)
{

   oneTwo.Stop();
   oneTwo.Children[0].SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, Target);
   oneTwo.Begin();
}

private void rotate2(object parameter, object secondParameter, String Target)
{
   twoThree.Stop();
   twoThree.Children[0].SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, Target);
   twoThree.Begin();
}

private void rotate1Inverse(object parameter, object secondParameter, string Target)
{
   twoOne.Stop();
   twoOne.Children[0].SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, Target);
   twoOne.Begin();
}

private void rotate2Inverse(object parameter, object secondParameter, string Target)
{
   threeTwo.Stop();
   threeTwo.Children[0].SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, Target.ToString());
   threeTwo.Begin();
}
```

**My Simulation Buttons**

```
//Rotate Buttons
private void button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec1Transform.CenterY = -10;

    rotate2(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec1Transform");
}

private void button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec2Transform.CenterX = -10;

    rotate1(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec2Transform");
}

private void button_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec3Transform.CenterY = -10;

    rotate1(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec3Transform");
}

private void button_Click4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec4Transform.CenterX = -10;

    rotate2(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec4Transform");
}

private void button_Click5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec5Transform.CenterY = -10;

    rotate2(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec5Transform");
}

private void button_Click6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec6Transform.CenterX = -10;

    rotate2(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec6Transform");
}

private void button_Click7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec7Transform.CenterY = -10;

    rotate1(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec7Transform");
}

//Inverse Rotate Buttons
private void button_Click1_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec1Transform.CenterY = 90;

    rotate1Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec1Transform");
}

private void button_Click2_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec2Transform.CenterX = 90;

    rotate2Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec2Transform");
}

private void button_Click3_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec3Transform.CenterY = 90;

    rotate2Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec3Transform");
}

private void button_Click4_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec4Transform.CenterX = 90;

    rotate1Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec4Transform");
}

private void button_Click5_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec5Transform.CenterY = 90;

    rotate1Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec5Transform");
}

private void button_Click6_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec6Transform.CenterX = 90;

    rotate1Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec6Transform");
}

private void button_Click7_Inverse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rec7Transform.CenterY = 90;

    rotate2Inverse(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty, "rec7Transform");
}
```

The problem is that I want to use these 4 basic storyboards SIMULTANEOUSLY on as many as 20 rectangles at a time, thereby animating all 20 rectangles in unison.  But I don't want a static storyboard assigned to each rectangle, because the storyboard I want to apply to each rectangle changes every second or so.  I will also be using all 4 storyboards at the same time. (i.e. I will use "oneTwo" for 3 of the rectangles, "twoThree" for 5 of the rectangles, "twoOne" for 8 of the rectangles, and "threeTwo" for 2 of the rectangles)

I hope that all makes sense.  The program is based solely on animating many rectangles at the same time, and any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you show all the objects in the layout. in a proper order like in a list or grid or improper.If you want to show in a proper way bind images to a stackpanel and animate

Comment: I posted my code for my rectangles above now, but how would I be able to animate all of the objects in a stackpanel at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be dumb or something, but I still can't figure this out.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Whats your actual need. do you have any samples

Comment: I updated my question and added some code to clarify things a bit.  Please let me know if something else doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the rectangles in a stackpanel

```
 <Listbox> 
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>        
  <DataTemplate> 
 <StackPanel>
 <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FirstStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                         From="0"
                         To="1"
                         //AutoReverse="True"
                         Duration="00:00:01" />
    </Storyboard>
 </StackPanel.Resources>
 <Rectangle Name="rectangle" Fill={Binding colour}>

 </Rectangle>

 </StackPanel>

 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </DataTemplate> 
 </Listbox>
```

Then Have a Binding in listbox with colours..refer binding in listbox items in web.

then with a button click start the story board. the storyboard children rectangles    increases its width

FirstStoryboard.begin();

Comment: I'm very familiar with Listbox, is it available for Windows Phone 7? Because Visual Studio 2010 isn't recognizing it in the xaml.